# Select inner most class on hover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to select inner most class when I have recursion in elements.
When you hover over `.comment` only this div's `.btn-reply` will be shown.
Elements are generated in PHP side (not included as not relevant).

So basically how to select most inner class element and not select same class element in parent elements (`.comment > .btn-reply` also check SO Snippet).

```css
.comment {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.comment .comment-header {
  height: 22px;
}
.comment .comment-header > .btn-reply {
  display: none;
}
.comment:hover > .comment-header > .btn-reply {
  display: inline;
}
button {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <div class="comment-header">
    <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="comment-header">
      <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="comment-header">
        <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="comment-header">
        <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="comment-header">
      <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="comment-header">
        <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
      </div>
      <div class="comment">
        <div class="comment-header">
          <button class="btn-reply">Show oly me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment">
        <div class="comment-header">
          <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment">
        <div class="comment-header">
          <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At quick glance, change `.comment:hover > .comment-header > .btn-reply` to `.comment > .comment-header:hover > .btn-reply`. (The problem is that when you hover over a nested `comment` you also always hover at its parent `comment(s)` thus `.comment:hover > .comment-header > .btn-reply` always applies to all of those).

Comment: You can't achieve this result with CSS, since hovering over a child hovers the parent also; to negate that (or adapt to that) we'd need a parent-selector (which doesn't yet exist, outside of the 'complete' profile of the CSS4 selectors module).

Comment: Just to clarify, do you absolutely have to target the comment block (.comment)? Can you just target the comment-header div instead to achieve the effect? e.g. comment-header:hover > .btn-reply  that will then only show the button in that particular header

Comment: @Sephorra Yes, because below `.comment-header` goes `.comment-text` that is on same level, so I need to show button when hovering on `.comment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is not possible to select first parent of element, all I had to do is to wrap `.content-header` and any other content of comment in block that breaks nesting.

```css
.btn-reply {
  display: none;
}
.comment {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.comment .comment-header {
  height: 22px;
}
.comment-wrapper:hover .btn-reply {
  display: inline;
}
button {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <div class="comment-wrapper">
    <div class="comment-header">
      <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-content">
      Some comment here
      <br/>More content
      <br/>And more content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comment">
    <div class="comment-wrapper">
      <div class="comment-header">
        <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-content">
        Some comment here
        <br/>More content
        <br/>And more content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="comment-wrapper">
        <div class="comment-header">
          <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-content">
          Some comment here
          <br/>More content
          <br/>And more content
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment">
        <div class="comment-wrapper">
          <div class="comment-header">
            <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
          </div>
          <div class="comment-content">
            Some comment here
            <br/>More content
            <br/>And more content
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="comment-wrapper">
        <div class="comment-header">
          <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-content">
          Some comment here
          <br/>More content
          <br/>And more content
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="comment-wrapper">
      <div class="comment-header">
        <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-content">
        Some comment here
        <br/>More content
        <br/>And more content
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hover` on the `.comment-header` as other `.comment-headers`'s aren't nested in there:

```
.comment > .comment-header:hover > .btn-reply {
  display: inline;
}
```

---

```css
.btn-reply
{
    display:none;
}

.comment {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.comment .comment-header {
  height: 22px;
}

.comment > .comment-header:hover > .btn-reply {
  display: inline;
}
button {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <div class="comment-header">
    <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="comment-header">
      <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="comment-header">
        <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="comment-header">
        <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="comment-header">
      <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="comment-header">
        <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
      </div>
      <div class="comment">
        <div class="comment-header">
          <button class="btn-reply">Show oly me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment">
        <div class="comment-header">
          <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment">
        <div class="comment-header">
          <button class="btn-reply">Show only me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

How about adding  `:last-child`  to your comment header

```
.comment:hover > .comment-header:last-child > .btn-reply {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: It will not work, because hovering on first `.comment` will not show `.btn-reply`

Comment: Sorry, I miss-read when you said the inner-most. comment-header:hover  as above will do the trick.